# find cells that contain keywords in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to write a macro that searches through a column in a database and returns, in a different tab, all the cells that contain a certain given keyword. In other words, I want to type in "hammer" and get a list of every cell that contains the word hammer, even if the word is in the middle of the value (for example, "the builder bought a hammer yesterday").

I'm fairly new to VBA so I would like some help/input on what functions to use to do this. I've tried to use AdvancedFilter, however that only looks at the very beginning of each cell value. All feedback is welcome, thank you!

Comment: Do you mean a database or a table in Excel? I'm pretty sure if it is all in Excel you don't need VBA. You just need some Excel formulae

Comment: Clarify your answer please. If not you'll tend to get down-voted and no-one will bother with your question.

Answer (score 0):

use [Autofilter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) method of `Range` object

```
Sub main()
    With Worksheets("hammer") '<--| reference searched worksheet (change "hammer" to its actual name)
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column "A" cells from row 1 down to last non empty one (change "A"s to your actual searched column index)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*hammer*" '<--| filter on referenced column to get cell containing "hammer"
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("different tab").Range("A1") '<--| copy any filtered cell into "different tab" worksheet
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| show all rows back
    End With
End Sub
```

it assumes the first cell of searched range ("A1" in this example) is a *header* cell, so that it won't be searched for "*hammer".